# What is the adjective corresponding to the humanities?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, difference

What adjective do you use for research carried out within the humanities? I've tried to consult dictionaries and google, but I only get more confused... so, if I want to use an adjective + noun to express 'research in the humanities', what should I use? *Humanistic research*? *Humanist research*? *Humanities research*? Or something else entirely?

As always I'm very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Humanities research* is fairly common and definitely understandable.

Here are some published examples:

> Data and its technologies now play a large and growing role in humanities research and teaching.

[The Shape of Data in Digital Humanities](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Shape_of_Data_in_Digital_Humanities/sTz3DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22humanities+research%22&printsec=frontcover)

> The volume explores the intra- and extra-academic engagement of humanities researchers

[Mapping Frontier Research in the Humanities](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mapping_Frontier_Research_in_the_Humanit/8Z8yEAAAQBAJ?hl=en)

> Humanities research often involves an individual professor researching in a library in order to write a book.

[How is humanities research conducted?](https://shc.stanford.edu/how-humanities-research-conducted)

*Humanist research* is more typically research that is conducted by Humanists, or which aims to promote Humanism.

> Rome was an early center of humanist research and, during the second half of the fifteenth century, numerous Latin comedies and tragedies were being staged...

[A Cultural History of Theatre in the Early Modern Age](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Cultural_History_of_Theatre_in_the_Ear/cYinDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22humanist+research%22&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover)

> Humanist education research is centrally concerned with promoting equity and social justice through research relationships. Humanist research takes as its starting point the dignity and humanity of all people.

[The Wiley Handbook of Ethnography of Education](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Wiley_Handbook_of_Ethnography_of_Edu/Bp1PDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22humanist+research%22&pg=PT225&printsec=frontcover)

It appears the *humanistic research* is used occasionally, though far less often than *humanities research*: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humanities+research%2Chumanistic+research&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumanities%20research%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumanistic%20research%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What an absolutely wonderful answer!!! Thank you so much!